# Store/Search IP Addresses in a Custom Object

Tags: soql, data

I needs to be able to store/search IP addresses/ranges for customers in a custom object so the addresses can be pushed to a third party system that grants access to a website via an institution's IP address. I am trying to work out the best way to store the data so that a user can check if a new IP address already belongs to an institution in the system.

In MySQL, you'd use something like the INET_ATON and INET_NTOA as described here so you could do a numerical search:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982701/best-way-to-store-ip-in-database

Is there an equivalent in SFDC? Seems like the alternative would be a wildcard search which would likely be slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement those two functions in Salesforce and then store the result on your records. The field could be indexed and made unique using an External Id flag on the field which would prevent duplicates across records where an address already existed on another institution.

Here's some exec anon code that you could adapt into a utility class or maybe a really complicated formula field. This is based on the example you provided about the [INET_ATON function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton).

> mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('10.0.5.9');
>
> ```
>     -> 167773449
> ```
>
> For this example, the return value is calculated as 10×256<sup>3</sup> + 0×256<sup>2</sup> + 5×256 + 9.

```
String ipAddress = '10.0.5.9';
List<String> octets = ipAddress.split('\\.');
Double numericValue = 0;

if (octets.size() == 4) {
    Double octet1 = Double.valueOf(octets[0]) * Math.pow(256, 3);
    Double octet2 = Double.valueOf(octets[1]) * Math.pow(256, 2);
    Double octet3 = Double.valueOf(octets[2]) * Math.pow(256, 1);
    Double octet4 = Double.valueOf(octets[3]) * Math.pow(256, 0);

    numericValue = octet1 + octet2 + octet3 + octet4;
}

system.debug(numericValue.format());
```

> `USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|167,773,449`